# How can I bulk upload my files to Google Docs and preserve the folder structuring?

Tags: google-drive, backup, upload

If I have a bunch of files all organized into a folder structure and I want to import those documents into Google Docs, is there an easy way to preserve all the folder structuring without having to upload and label them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that now that there is Google Drive, you can just drag-and-drop the folder from your file browser into the Google Drive webpage to import the whole folder (and keeping the file directory structure intact at the same time).

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a way to do it from the web interface, but there is an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs) for uploading documents.

The [google-docs-upload](http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-upload/) project seems to be exactly what you want, although I've not tried it myself.

Comment: The author's blog describes its usage here: http://blog.beloglazov.info/2009/09/google-docs-batch-upload-en.html